# How to change Font and text color, border color in Gantt chart Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to change font family, font size, font color so that my entire chart should have same font and color.
I know using style [api](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.style) i can do that but it only changes in some places
[Here i want blue border everywhere but I see option to set border color for xAxis, YAxis, and chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llOp9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llOp9.png)

But this does not look good.
Is there way i can set border color, font size, font family, font color all these css styles so that entire chart looks uniform to me.

```
      [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/manshi44/pen/OJaXOOr)
```

Tried api https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.style and few other to change styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the font, just set `chart.style.fontFamily` property:

```js
chart: {
  style: {
    fontFamily: 'Fasthand'
  }
}
```

As for text color, you can set styles for each element, you can do this for `title`, axis `labels`, `credits` and all the rest:

```js
title: {
  style: {
    color: 'red'
  }
}
```

Border color you need to remember about the `grid`, `tick` and `lines` of all axes, there are 2 x-axes in the gant by default, separate for months and separate for years:

```js
xAxis: [{
  gridLineColor: 'blue',
  tickColor: 'blue',
  lineColor: 'blue'
}, {
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  tickColor: 'blue',
  lineColor: 'blue'
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lj6xbo8/

**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.style 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.style.color 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.style.color 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits.style.color

Comment: Hey Michal,
Thanks again. Few things I was able to figure out from documentation. Thanks for quick response